# How to check the resolution of converted raster file

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have a raster file whose resolution I need to change to 0.5. I do this using this:

`g.region rast=my_raster res=0.5`

After running this command, how do I verify whether the resolution has actually changed to 0.5?

Comment: I was under the impression that resolution of all rasters within a grass workspace were controlled at the workspace level, and that if you wanted to change the resolution, you would change it at the workspace level. Rasters with multiple resolutions were not possible... but I could be wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the g.region you used does not change the resolution of your raster layer. In general, what you do with the g.region function is setting the 'working resolution' and extent. In the case of your example, you are telling grass to use the extent of the raster layer my_raster and a resolution of 0.5. Functions will use that resolution rather than the raster resolution.

You can use the g.region also to check the current resolution by typing on the command line:

```
g.region -p
```

If your raster layer is at a different resolution than set by g.region, grass will re-sample it on the fly when used as input in a function. It uses the nearest neighbour method for that.

If the nearest neighbour re-sampling is not appropriate, you need to create a new layer first. After setting the resolution using g.region you can use one of the re-sample functions in the raster menu (`raster - develop raster map`)

You can subsequently check the resolution of the layer using the r.info function. You can find the r.info function in the raster menu:  `raster - reports and statistics`. Or you can type on the command line:

```
r.info map=my_layer
```

For more information see [this page on raster data processing](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/rasterintro.html) on the grass wiki.